# How do you select specific data in columns (Database)

Tags: sql, database, select

I am trying to get my php to select data from a columns that MUST = 1
Here is how it is sorted:

```
Name  SteamID  RANK      SID
User1 Example1 Owner      1
User2 Example2 Superadmin 0
User3 Example3 User       1
User3 Example4 Guest      1
```

What I want to select is SID however it must = 1

Comment: Have you done any research? What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query for the whole row is

```
select * 
  from mytable
  where sid=1
```

But you said you want to get the value of SID and it must be 1.  So you would write

```
select sid 
  from mytable
  where sid=1
```

But if you do that, all you will get is

```
SID
 1
 1
 1
```

Which doesn't seem too useful.  Presumably you want to select some other column(s)

```
select name, steamid, rank 
  from mytable
  where sid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select it where the SID does equal 1

```
SELECT Name, SteamID, RANK FROM table WHERE `SID` = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree- this is best handled in the SQL call, using the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT [Column-Name]
FROM [Table-Name]
WHERE 'SID'=1
```

Comment: This answer appears to be specifically for Microsoft databases, since [ ] is not standard syntax.  A portable answer might be more helpful since the post did not say `SQL Server`.